# back up android db on cloud?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Is it ok to save sqlite db of android app to google drive for backup/restore purpose instead of sdcard ?

Also is it ok to save/update .db file to cloud on every change/in interval?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html

Comment: SD card is faster, and you don't have to pay data charges.  But sure, Google Drive is a viable - fully supported - alternative.

Comment: Concerning the suggested *Backup API*, please keep in mind following note from the official documentation: _"The backup service is not designed for synchronizing application data with other clients or saving data that you'd like to access during the normal application lifecycle. You cannot read or write backup data on demand and cannot access it in any way other than through the APIs provided by the Backup Manager."_

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, Google Drive is a perfectly good option for this use-case. Personally, I would back up to the SD card, and then sync that backup with Google Drive. Perhaps offering the user the option of when to do the sync so it might only happen over WiFi, etc.